# How to redirect to another page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to redirect to another page in reactjs. Here is my code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import MoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';

export default function PrimarySearchAppBar() {
  function logout(){
    this.props.history.push({pathname:'/'})
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to redirect its sayas "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

how can i fix this?

Comment: You're using functional component, there's no `this.props`.You need to pass props as an arg to the function `export default function PrimarySearchAppBar(props) {`.

Comment: well, it's not really a component you have there, you just export a function, where do you think `this.props` would come from?

Comment: I am new in reactjs so I don't know how to do this. Can you give me some references?

Comment: there is blank result comming when I use "export default function PrimarySearchAppBar(props) {}" @Clarity

Comment: Because you need to pass those props when invoking `PrimarySearchAppBar`. Where are you using it?

Comment: Its a navbar which I copied from material ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component should look  something like this

```
class PrimarySearchAppBar extends React.PureComponent {
  logout = () => {
    this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/' });
  }

  render() {
    // some render logic here
    return <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>;
  }
}

export default PrimarySearchAppBar;
```

Or with stateless components like this

```
const logout = (props) => {
  props.history.push({ pathname: '/' });
}

const PrimarySearchAppBar = (props) => {
  // some render logic here
  return <button onClick={() => logout(props)}>Logout</button>;
}

export default PrimarySearchAppBar;
```

Be careful that with stateless components, you can't use `this` keyword, but you have to pass it like standard paramater.

Comment: Why not use `Link` instead?

Comment: Because I write some logic before log out from the web app. @lcepickle

Comment: I got this error when use stateless method "TopNavBar.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: @Keerti, you need to wrap the component with `withRouter` if you want to access `history` object's properties. `export default withRouter(PrimarySearchAppBar);`. Also, import it from `react-router-dom`.

Comment: Either wrap it with `withRouter` or you have to pass history object to the component

`<PrimarySearchAppBar history={history} />`

Comment: export default withRouter(PrimarySearchAppBar); this option work for me. thanks @vipulp 
Thanks everyone for the help , Icepickle, Tomas Bruckner